# In ExtJS 4.1 dragdropzones example, how could I move the patients to the hospitals and do it by multi-selecting?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4.1

In this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/dd/dragdropzones.html) of ExtJS 4.1, actually the left elements (patients) are cloned from the view to the right grid (Hospitals) I want to remove the patients of the left view when I drag and drop to the right grid, and add the capacity to move the items from the right grid to the left view:

I made the first part (moving to the right) with a trick (slideOut) I did it with this:

before at the function initializePatientDragZone I added:

```
return v.dragData = {
    sourceEl: sourceEl,
    repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY(),
    ddel: d,
    patientData: v.getRecord(sourceEl).data,
    patientElement: sourceEl //This part
};
```

and then I added one slideOut trick like this, at the onNodeDrop function:

```
onNodeDrop : function(target, dd, e, data){

var rowBody = Ext.fly(target).findParent('.x-grid-rowbody-tr', null, false),
    mainRow = rowBody.previousSibling,
    h = gridView.getRecord(mainRow),
    targetEl = Ext.get(target);

    targetEl.update(data.patientData.name + ', ' + targetEl.dom.innerHTML);

    //this slideOut
    Ext.get(data.patientElement).slideOut('t', {
    easing: 'easeOut',
    duration: 500,
    remove: true,
    useDisplay: true
});

return true;
}
```

---

You can see how it looks now : [in this animation](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/544/celvindraganddropcustom.gif)

now I just want to move the items at the right grid to the left view.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to do in your explanation, I don't understand what slid-out has to do with removing nodes...

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this kind of functionality in an earlier project using the grid-to-grid DND plugin.

For example, one grid of patients, three other grids for the three hospitals.

Layout the grids as siblings and the only additional configs you need for them is this:

```
multiSelect: true,
viewConfig: {
    plugins: {
        ptype:'gridviewdragdrop'
    }
},
```

You will be able to multi-select them back and forth and you don't have to mess around with drop zones. It was the easiest way to achieve the functionality you want.